# mysqli insert to database not working

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I'm trying to insert data into my MySQL table, but not working!
My code:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn44'])){
        $fname=$_POST['fname'];
        $lname=$_POST['lname'];
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `mss_user` (`fname`,`lname`) VALUES ('$fname','$lname')");
}
```

The connection is fine, returns no errors.

Comment: This information is incomplete to identify your problem!! please post your full code

Comment: And you're sure that is actually getting executed?  Did you try echoing something out inside of that if statement?

Comment: please paste your full code. because this much code seem fine.

Comment: your code is looks good! more information required!

Comment: The only thing that I could possible see that is "wrong" with your code is the lack of a semi-colon at the end of your sql statement, but I do not believe that would break this code.

Comment: _The connection is fine, returns no errors._ But what about other PHP errors

Comment: echo $mysqli->error;

Comment: this is show mysql error,"doesn't have have default value"

Comment: thank you all!!the problem is solved:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 echo "INSERT INTO `mss_user` (`fname`,`lname`) VALUES ('$fname','$lname')";
 $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `mss_user` (`fname`,`lname`) VALUES ('$fname','$lname')");
```

then you can read real query and copy this string and paste in mysql client or phpmyadmin page.

Comment: And how does this make difference with the OPs query

Answer (score 0):

First of all, does your connect the Database ?
Second thing, if you check the result with bamtoggi suggestion, and if there is nothing in the place of $fname and $lname, you should try to extract data value from string like this :

```
   $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `mss_user` (`fname`,`lname`) VALUES (' "+$fname+" ',' "+$lname+" ');");
```

Let us know.

Comment: Are you ok. Is this going to work `VALUES (' "+$fname+" ',' "+$lname+" ');"`?

Comment: This doesn't make any differences and I doubt about your concatenation operator its `PHP(.)` not `JS(+)`

Comment: Firstly, Uchima is right, operator is '.' instead of '+' and for sur, my suggestion shouldn't make any difference, but with this solution you delete any error of php string parsing.